# Coefficient Correlation r of Exponential Functions Regression

Tags: statistics, exponential-function, regression

I'm writing an exponent regression calculator $Ae^{Bx}$
Sample Data Set (X,Y) is

```
(9, 1)
(7, 10)
(6,11)
(20, 10)
(15, 1)
```

**A = 5.287 and B = -0.0232**. So $F(x) = 5.287e^{-0.0232x}$ which is fine.

However, what is the right formula to calculate Coefficients Correlation r ?

1. $r = \sqrt{R2} = \sqrt{1 - \frac {RSS}{TSS}}$ which can not be applied because R2 = -0.275
   [Reference Here](http://ocw.usu.edu/Civil_and_Environmental_Engineering/Uncertainty_in_Engineering_Analysis/Regression_DataFitting_Part2.pdf)
2. $r = \sqrt{\frac {ESS}{TSS}} = 0.311$
   [Reference Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwihmovnv9jMAhUiR48KHU1-Ap4QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.suu.edu%2Ffaculty%2Fberri%2Fppt%2Fsensem%2Fsensemregress3.pptx&usg=AFQjCNGcbM5PtWDeQzgmEXuU6nsqlkGLqA&bvm=bv.122129774,d.c2I)
3. $r = \frac {\sum{(X-\bar X)(Y-\bar Y)}}{\sqrt{\sum{(X-\bar X)^{2}} \sum{(Y-\bar Y)^{2}}}}  = -0.00109$
4. On the other hand, My Casio FX570 give $r = -1.0782$ (with the same A & B)

Which one is correct and what is the formula that Casio use ?

Comment: Why is this fine ? Your data are far away to be exponential distributed. You get for the x-values 7 and 20 the y-value 10 and for the x-value 15 the y-value 1. How on earth you can think that there is a trend in your data ? You have to choose data with an (exponential) trend. Please make an edit of your question.

Comment: Hi, Thanks @callculus . I know that but I get the same result as Casio with exponential trend data set. just curiosity want to know if there is any other Coefficient Correlation, or how Casio calculate them.

Comment: If you choose data with an exponential trend then it make sense to check the calculations. The value of r has no meaning for that kind of data set-regardless how r is calculated.